# Django RF Writable Nested Serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a writable nested serializer in DRF3. 
I have a model Concert with a m2m field 'technicians' to my User-model. 
I have successfully added a list of the Users that is connected to the Concert instance in it's view. Now I want to be able to add technicians/Users to the Concert-model.

This is my serializer so far:

```
class ConcertListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    technicians = UserDetailSerializer(
            many=True,
            read_only=True
        )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Concert
        fields = [
            'name',
            'date',
            'technicians',
            'id',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # list of pk's
        technicians_data = validated_data.pop('technicians')
        concert = Concert.object.create(**validated_data)

        for tech in technicians_data:
            tech, created = User.objects.get(id = tech) 
            concert.technicians.add({
                    "name": str(tech.name),
                    "email": str(tech.email),
                    "is_staff": tech.is_staff,
                    "is_admin": tech.is_admin,
                    "is_superuser": tech.is_superuser,
                    "groups": tech.groups,
                    "id": tech.id
                })
        return concert
```

I want to be able to just add a list of the pk/id of the technicians I want to add. So for example:

```
"technicians": [1,2,3]
```

adds user 1, 2, 3 to Concert's technicians-field.

Whenever I do this, I get KeyError that just says 'technicians' and refers to the first line in my create() function...

The fields I am adding in a dictionary are all the fields of the User-model. That is the format they are displayed when I do a GET-request.

This is the Concert-model:

```
class Concert(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default =
                                datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Oslo'))
                                + timedelta(days=30)
                            )
    technicians = models.ManyToManyField(User)  # relation to user model
```

Edit:
This is the response of a GET-request on a premade example-concert:

```
{
    "name": "Concert-name",
    "date": "2017-10-28T12:11:26.180000Z",
    "technicians": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": "test2@test.com",
            "is_staff": true,
            "is_admin": true,
            "is_superuser": false,
            "groups": [
                5
            ],
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": "test3@test.com",
            "is_staff": true,
            "is_admin": true,
            "is_superuser": false,
            "groups": [
                5
            ],
            "id": 3
        }
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get data from context request, because you filed is read only it is missing in the `validated_data`

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    # list of pk's
    # instaed of technicians_data = validated_data.pop('technicians')
    # use next two lines
    request = self.context.get('request')
    technicians_data = request.data.get('technicians')

    concert = Concert.object.create(**validated_data)

    # Added technicians
    for tech in technicians_data:
        user = User.objects.get(id=tech) 
        concert.technicians.add(user)

    return concert
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot, but DRF Documentation says to do it as I did: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: i added description why you can use it.

Comment: Also which params should I give Concert.object.create()?

Comment: Alright I removed the read_only, and now I get the data. Problem now is that django expects to get the full user-dictionary in the POST-request. I get NoneField errors. How do I get Django to accept a list of IDs, and then let my create()-method construct the dictionary?

Comment: you need return back `read_only` and then get data from request as i write in the answer

Comment: Then what parameters should I create the Concert instance with? As you can see, I now create it with the validated_data list, without 'technicians'.

Comment: I have to remove read_only. If I don't I get an error because I include technicians in POST

Comment: your `Concert` is created by valid code, you need replace code for add `technicians` to the instance, i updated the answer

Comment: Worked. Thanks alot!